# How do I customise table names in grails nimble?

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, nimble

I installed the Nimble 0.7 plugin for Grails just now, and have a running instance, but I now want to customise the table names. I followed the instructions in [the plugin’s guide](http://snimavat.github.io/nimble/guide/configuration.html) and restarted my app, but nothing happens. I also tried to manually delete the tables and restart the app, and it generated the tables with their original names.

NimbleConfig.groovy

```
nimble {
    ....
    tablenames {
        user = "auth_user"
        role = "auth_role"
        group = "auth_group"
        profilebase = "auth_profile_base"
        loginrecord = "auth_login_record"
        permission = "auth_permission"
        levelpermission = "auth_level_permission"
        url = "auth_url"
    }
    ....
}
```

Comment: What does your NimbleConfig.groovy look like?

Comment: I updated my question with my additions to the NimbleConfig.groovy file.

Comment: Well this is strange. I invoked `run-app` just now, and the new tables have now been created... I've made no change to the app since posting this question! I have the project open in Intellij IDEA at the same time as it runs in Grails interactive mode, but even that was the case when I asked this question.

Comment: Gawd, I hate it when things resolve "by themselves"--no opportunity to learn!